# Write XML based on class created from XSD - issue

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

I have create a VB.net class from a quite complex XSD via XSD.exe

The class looks like this (with very much more following)

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Partial Public Class barbadosImportFile
    
    Private informationField As importInformationType
    
    Private b2bDebtorsField() As importB2BDebtorType
    
    Private b2cDebtorsField() As importB2CDebtorType
    
    Private riskAssociationDebtorsField() As importRiskAssociationDebtorType
    
    Private vouchersField() As importVoucherType
    
    Private riskAssociationAssignmentsField() As importRiskAssociationAssignmentType

    Private securitiesField() As importSecurityType
....
```

Now in my code following works without issues

```
     Dim debXML As New barbadosImportFile

    debXML.information = New importInformationType
    debXML.information.timeStamp = Now()
    debXML.information.systemName = "Presystem"
    debXML.information.numberOfSecurities = 2


    Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(barbadosImportFile))
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\hhl.CORPORATE\OneDrive - Ingram Micro\Desktop\debitex.xml")
    serializer.Serialize(writer, debXML)
    writer.Close()
```

This creates an XML looking like the sample I wanted, but part of the sample should also be some other elements like b2bdebtors,b2cdebtors,riskAssociationDebtors,vouchers,riskAssociationAssignments - all without data, and especially securities - security where I have the basic data I need to include

The XML should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<barbadosImportFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <information>
    <timeStamp>2021-04-01T15:52:57.727846+01:00</timeStamp>
    <systemName>Presystem</systemName>
    <numberOfB2BDebtors>0</numberOfB2BDebtors>
    <numberOfB2CDebtors>0</numberOfB2CDebtors>
    <numberOfRiskAssociationDebtors>0</numberOfRiskAssociationDebtors>
    <numberOfVouchers>0</numberOfVouchers>
    <numberOfRiskAssociationAssignments>0</numberOfRiskAssociationAssignments>
    <numberOfSecurities>1</numberOfSecurities>
    <numberOfLimits>0</numberOfLimits>
    <numberOfUsers>0</numberOfUsers>
    <numberOfSalesRepresentativeDebtorAssignments>0</numberOfSalesRepresentativeDebtorAssignments>
    <numberOfSoftfactScorings>0</numberOfSoftfactScorings>
    <numberOfExternalIdentifiers>0</numberOfExternalIdentifiers>
    <numberOfVoucherAdditionals>0</numberOfVoucherAdditionals>
    <numberOfDebtorAdditionals>0</numberOfDebtorAdditionals>
    <numberOfCompanyBlacklists>0</numberOfCompanyBlacklists>
    <numberOfPersonBlacklists>0</numberOfPersonBlacklists>
  </information>
  <b2bDebtors />
  <b2cDebtors />
  <riskAssociationDebtors />
  <vouchers />
  <riskAssociationAssignments />
  <securities>
    <security>
      <createdAt>2021-04-01T00:00:00</createdAt>
      <comment />
```

But i don´t know how to initiate those array-fields?

something like

```
debXML.b2bDebtors(0) = New importB2BDebtorType
```

Throws a "object not set to instance of object"

Unfortunately I failed to find a solution googling it.

Any help?

Comment: Private properties do not get serialized.  You need to change the private properties to public.

Comment: @jdweng that is only start of the class made from xsd, as you can see eg
Private informationField As importInformationType
importInformationType is a partial public class having private fields, but public properties getting/setting the values. Serialization works perfectly fine for the "information" as per my code - I just don´t know how to deal with the array fields (such as   Private securitiesField() As importSecurityType

Answer (score 0):

Ok, googling some more I found something that worked:

```
debXML.securities = New importSecurityType(intSize) {}

For i = 0 To intSize
    debXML.securities(i) = New importSecurityType()
Next
```

This will allow to access the properties like that

```
debXML.securities(0).companyCode = "AT"
```

And Serialization works perfectly fine as per XSD defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication189
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //BarbadosImportFile BarbadosImportFile = new BarbadosImportFile()
            //{
            //    security = new List<Security>() {
            //       new Security() { createdAt = new DateTime(2014,4,1)}
            //   }
            //};
            //XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            //settings.Indent = true;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BarbadosImportFile));
            BarbadosImportFile barbadosImportFile = (BarbadosImportFile)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
           
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("barbadosImportFile")]
    public class BarbadosImportFile
    {
        [XmlArray("securities")]
        [XmlArrayItem("security")]
        public List<Security> security { get; set; }
    }
    public class Security
    {
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
    }

  
}
```